# Insert command VB SQL DB

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

This is my code. I want to be able to insert data into a rota table. When it compiles, it compiles with no errors. The problem comes when clicking the button. The error i get is: **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.**

```
 Dim Con As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim sqlstring As String
    Dim connstring As String
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter



    connstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Assignment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"

    Con = New SqlConnection(connstring)
    Con.Open()


    sqlstring = ("Insert into Rota WHERE Id ='" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' and Monday ='" & mon & "' and Tuesday ='" & tues & "'and Wednesday ='" & wed & "'and Thursday ='" & thur & "'and Friday ='" & fri & "'and Saturday ='" & sat & "'and Sunday ='" & sun & "' and UserID ='" & cboname.SelectedIndex & "'")
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlstring, Con)
    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "Rota")
```

Comment: This will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: What are you inserting? You need to have a `VALUES` clause in your insert statement. Also, you are not `Fill()`-ing a dataset. You are changing the database. Use `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` instead.

Comment: It compiles because everything is valid from VB's perspective. Things are going awry in your SQL statement.

Comment: Joel I realised id made a mistake after i posted this, and stared at it for a little longer. This is what my sqltring looks like now: `sqlstring = ("Insert into Rota (Id, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday,Sunday,UserID) values(DateTimePicker1.Value, mon, tues, Wed, Thurs, fri, sat, sun, user")`   The error received now is: Incorrect syntax near 'user'.